# Why is the moderator trying to hide the fact?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194880/an-accurate-answer-to-one-of-my-questions-was-deleted-how-can-i-recover-it) asks for an answer to be recovered despite the OP's rudeness against the answerer as shown in the comment below made by the OP to the answerer:

[image]

To that meta question, an answer was posted by me telling a hint to why the answer was deleted. The moderator [Andrew Barber](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152134/andrew-barber) deleted that answer. This moderator also deleted a comment asking for an apology. Why is the moderator trying to hide the rudeness of the user [Anderson Green](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177227/anderson-green)?

Who would want to help anyone who gives a rude comment like the one shown above?

Comment: I am trying to handle each of your behaviors appropriately. You are apparently refusing to cooperate. Very well.

Comment: You tried to hide how rude the OP was to me. Why do you hide that?

Comment: You're not really doing yourself favours here either

Comment: I also tried to hide how rude you were to the OP. That's my job. to remove that sort of crap.

Comment: The rudeness started from Anderson Green.

Comment: It doesn't matter who started it. I don't allow any of it to remain.

Comment: How do you judge the comment captured above? If it were you, would you want to help an OP who writes to you something like that?

Comment: @sawa My comment wasn't intended to be rude: I was actually grateful for the constructive criticism that I had been given. I'm also very thankful for the answer that you posted, even though it was deleted soon after being posted.

Comment: That cannot be read like that.

Comment: Self-deprecation, it's a fine art

Comment: @sawa Can you undelete the answer that you posted to my question? It was the best answer that I had seen to that particular question, so I'm a bit confused as to why it was deleted.

Comment: @Anderson I think it might boil down to taking offense at your (admittedly quite heavy) bit of sarcastic self-deprecation in the above-referenced comment.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I actually didn't intend it as sarcasm, although it was probably interpreted that way.

Comment: @Anderson OK, so, hyperbolic self-deprecation, then. :) Which can be construed in lots of ways, at times.

Comment: Public arguments rarely end well.  I speak from experience.  First one to walk away, wins.  Seriously.  I recommend you try it next time

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Why are you being so insistent about this?

No one here cares about your little feud (if you can even call it that). If you find a comment rude, flag it and let it be deleted. If you're offended in a way that makes you want to withdraw your answer from that question, all the power to you.

**Let it go and move on.**

Harassing users to apologize for a comment by posting additional comments and/or answers elsewhere - *not* the proper thing to do. That behavior is just as bad as, if not worse than, posting a slightly rude comment (that's already been deleted, nonetheless).

Comment: Yes. I withdrew my answer (deleted and removed the content), just like you wrote above. It was over at that point. Then the moderator Andrew Barber came in, and recovered the content.

Comment: @sawa: Editing in irrelevant content, even to a deleted answer, is not appropriate. If you had left the answer at Revision 2, a moderator probably would never have gotten involved and we wouldn't be having this discussion.

Comment: Then Andrew Barber should have rolled it back to Revision 2.

Comment: @sawa He did the first time, then you edited it again...

Comment: You are right. He did it once. Then after while (before I did anything), he rolled it back to the initial state.

Comment: sawa is right there; I originally edited back to the dashes, then back to the original when I realised my mistake. But animuson is more right here: I'd not have done any rollback at all if what I'd seen was the dashes to begin with.